# adding elements from jtextarea to jlist by clicking on jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jtextarea, defaultlistmodel

i have a jtextfield where i can add an element and by clicking on a button i want to add it to the jlist,
now the problem i am having is that by clicking on the button it will add the element i want but when i add another element to the list the old one is gone and a new one appears in it's place.
here is the code i have:

```
 private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    

    DefaultListModel  model1= new DefaultListModel();

    model1.addElement(desc.getText());
    jList2.setModel(model1);
    jList2.setSelectedIndex(0);
    desc.setText("");
}
```

can anyone help me with that?
Thank you

Comment: only to call `model1.addElement(desc.getText());` from `JButtons ActionListener`, don't to re_create `JList`, its `DeafaultListModel`, nor to add a new `Item(s)` this way to the already visible Swing GUI, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example. That is start with the tutorials for the basics, not the forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the button is clicked you are creating a new DefaultListModel and adding the element to this brand new list. Therefore you cannot add them all into the same list.

Instead define your DefaultListModel  model1 outside of `addActionPerformed` method and use the reference to the object inside like the following:

```
DefaultListModel  model1= new DefaultListModel();

private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
      model1.addElement(desc.getText());
      jList2.setModel(model1);
      jList2.setSelectedIndex(0);
      desc.setText("");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the `JList` model every time you click the `JButton`. Instead you could use a single `DefaultListModel` at class level at startup and add to that.

- [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Only once (may be in constructor),
// don't put this code in ActionListener method actionPerformed().
DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
```

Remaining code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listModel.addElement("Jane Doe");
    listModel.addElement("John Smith");
    listModel.addElement("Kathy Green");


    list = new JList(listModel);
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
    listModel.remove(index);

    int size = listModel.getSize();

    if (size == 0) { //Nobody's left, disable firing.
        fireButton.setEnabled(false);

    } else { //Select an index.
        if (index == listModel.getSize()) {
            //removed item in last position
            index--;
        }

        list.setSelectedIndex(index);
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible(index);
    }
}
```